# The `bounds` parameter in `angular-google-map` not working?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

See this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBw6SAAIgezpvp9ndMbP?p=preview)

In the [document](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api), I saw the description of `bounds` parameter is:

> Fit the map in the specified bounds. The expression must resolve to an
>   object having both northeast and southwest properties. Each of those
>   properties must have a latitude and a longitude properties

I set the bounds in scope:

```
$scope.bd = {
  northeast: {
    latitude: 51.219053,
    longitude: 4.404418
  },
  southwest: {
    latitude: -51.219053,
    longitude: -4.404418
  }
}
```

And used it in directive like this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map bounds="bd" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options"></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

But it seems that there is no effect.. the map is not fitted in my specified bounds.. Does that mean the bounds parameter is not working? And how to make the map to fit the specified bounds?

Answer (score 2):

Why not using center and zoom instead of bounds ?

Anyway, I was doing some tests and as the center, zoom and bounds are in a whatch inside a directive, those are loaded async, and as the center and zoom are required the bounds are not efected.

Even setting the value after it didn't change ( don't know why )

http://plnkr.co/edit/YdyYIiVVgApA2tpm11Xn?p=preview

```
setTimeout(function(){
  var map = $scope.instance.getGMap();
  console.log(map);
  console.log(map.getBounds());



$scope.bd = {
  northeast: {
    latitude: 51.219053,
    longitude: 4.404418
  },
  southwest: {
    latitude: -51.219053,
    longitude: -4.404418
  }
}

                    ne = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.bd.northeast.latitude, $scope.bd.northeast.longitude);
            sw = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.bd.southwest.latitude, $scope.bd.southwest.longitude);
            bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
map.fitBounds(bounds);



}, 2000);
```

Comment: I calculate my bounds dynamically, so all markers are in the view perfectly. This is not possible with only center and zoom.